# ffmpeg: combine filter_complex trim, overlay and concat

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, overlay

I try to combine different video and audio clips with trimming and a logo on top.

My syntax looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "$introVid" -i "$introAud" -i "$mainVid" -i "$mainAud" -i "$outroVid" -i "$outroAud" -i "$logo" -i "$mainVid" -i "$mainAud" \
-filter_complex \
"[2:0]trim=0.4:60[trimV1]; \
 [3:0]atrim=0.4:60[trimA1]; \
 [trimV1][6:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-20:15,fade=in:s=2:d=0.5:alpha=1,fade=out:s=60:d=0.5:alpha=1[fade]; \
 [7:0]trim=60.2:72[trimV2]; [8:0]atrim=60.2:72[trimA2]; \
 [0:0] [1:0] [fade] [trimA1] [4:0] [5:0] [trimV2] [trimA2] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[cv][a]; \
 [cv]scale=864:480:flags=gauss:interl=0[scal]" \
-map "[scal]" -map "[a]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset fast -y "$out"
```

It works mostly, but the problem is that I get a black video, with the same length then the main video, on the 3rd place. Interesting is also, when I watch the ffmpeg process, it hangs shortly on time 1:26min and then it jumps to 2:40min. Normally the complete test video have around 1:30min.

The output what I get is at the moment:

`([intro][trimmed main with logo][black video][outro][credits])` <- the black video part is to much.

Comment: The trim command needed a PTS Flags: for video= `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` and for audio= `asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS` .

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from your command.

Answer (score 4):

Without new pts, ffmpeg count the time wrong, after trimming. When some parts from a video needed to place more times, it is also not necessary to input them more times.

So here is the right syntax for that:

```
ffmpeg -i "$introVid" -i "$introAud" -i "$mainVid" -i "$mainAud" \ 
-i "$outroVid" -i "$outroAud" -i "$logo" -filter_complex "\
[2:v]trim=0.4:$cut,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[trimV1]; \
[3:a]atrim=0.4:$cut,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[trimA1]; \
[trimV1][6:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-20:15, \
fade=in:0:25,fade=out:$cuf:25[fade]; \
[2:v]trim=$cut:$len,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[trimV2]; \
[3:a]atrim=$cut:$len,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[trimA2]; \
[0:v] [1:a] [fade] [trimA1] [4:v] [5:a] [trimV2] [trimA2] \ 
concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[cv][a]; \
[cv]scale=864:480:flags=gauss:interl=0[scal]" \
-map "[scal]" -map "[a]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset fast -y "out.mp4"
```